# Excenter, External Angle Bisectors and Sides form cyclic quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry

> In $ABC$, the external angle bisectors of $B$ and $A$ intersect $AC$ and $BC$ at $F$ and $H$, respectively. If $BF\cap AH=G$, $FH=1$, and $GFHC$ is cyclic, find $FG+GH$.
>   https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/mwe77yst

By definition, $G$ is the A-excenter. By the incenter-excenter lemma, $GC$ is the angle bisector of $\angle{ACB}$. Since $GFHC$ is cyclic,
$$\angle{GHF}=\angle{ACG}=\angle{GCB}=\angle{GFH}$$
Thus, $FG=GH$. This is as far angle chasing has gotten me, so I tried to find out how the $FH$ condition can be used. Ptolemy on GFHC doesn't work, and there are no relations to $FH$ on other sides. Thanks!

Edit: I found a configuration extremely similar to this on wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem
The exterior angle bisectors section gives some ratios, but I don't know how to apply them.